# Getting value of a variable from other file php

Tags: php, authentication, variables, post, get

How will I get the value of variable username from login.php and pass to the query of get.php
[Login.php](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PXSmC.png)

[get.php](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uSXPl.png)

Comment: Probably using the Session...but it depends on the purpose and context, of which we've got none. Please read [ask] and try again

Comment: Also as per the [How To Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) guide, which you are encouraged to read before using the site, please don't post images of your code. Code is text. Pasting it as graphics is very impractical as it can't be copied, searched, re-used in answers etc. It makes it difficult for those who might want to help you. Please edit your question to include the code as text and use the [formatting tools](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) to present it nicely, so that it is usable for those who want to help you. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

At the beginning of both files, you should start a session:

```
<?php
session_start();
?>
```

Then you should put the username in a session, like shown below:

```
<?php
if (!empty($_POST["username"]) {
    $_SESSION["username"] = $_POST["username"];
} else {
    echo "<p>You didn't fill in a username</p>";
}
?>
```

Then in the get.php file remove the "require_once login.php" line, and add the variable $username like so:

```
<?php
$username = $_SESSION["username"];
$sql = "SELECT firstname, contactnum FROM tb_register  WHERE username= '".$username."'";
?>
```

Comment: You are suggesting SQL injection

Comment: Where did I suggest that?

Comment: In `$sql = ...`

Comment: I just copied the code from the user, I simply didn't add the STMT variable because I didn't deem it necessary since I didn't change anything about it.